# Confusion with syntax for postfix expressions and operators

Tags: c++, syntax

In the following case,

```
int i = 0;
int j = 42;
i = j++;
```

I know `++` is posfix operator, So, is `j` a posfix expression or should you say`j++` is posfix expression ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syntactically, both `j` and `j++` are postfix-expressions.

See the grammar in section 5.2 of the C++ 2003 standard:

```
postfix-expression:
    primary-expression
    ...
    postfix-expression ++
```

(`j` is also a primary-expression; `j++` is not.)

The fact that a primary-expression is a kind of postfix-expression (even if it doesn't contain a postfix operator) is mostly a matter of convenience for defining the language syntax.  There's not much point in referring to `j` as a postfix-expression unless you're talking about parsing C++ (or C) source code.

Comment: does this means a postfix expression can be a primary expression and vice-versa?

Comment: It means that all primary-expressions are also postfix-expressions, but the reverse is not the case.  `j` is both a primary-expression and a postfix-expression; `j++` is a postfix-expression but not a primary-expression.